# getline going over specified amount

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, getline

I have this code....

```
    file_parser::file_parser(string file){
        txtfile.open(file.c_str(), ios::in);
        if (!txtfile.good()){
            string error=err(0," "+file+" not found. Exit code ",1);
            throw file_parse_exception(error);
        }
        while (!txtfile.eof()){
            char str[200];
            txtfile.getline(str, 200);
            string str2=str;
            vfile.push_back(str2);
        }
        txtfile.close();
    }
```

and the problem is that if I have a line in the input file greater than 200 characters it hangs then crashes. I checked out the value of str at crash and it is preceded by a null char then it tries to push back a null(non-initialized) string onto the vector which causes the hang/crash. does anyone know a way to get around this? I thought by using getline it would truncate the char array at 199(+null) characters but apparently this isn't happening. I'm stumped. The thing is that I want each pushback to have a max of 200 characters. I really don't want the WHOLE line which is what 'string str' would do. and if a line is over 200 characters it should read the first 200 and then move on to the next line.

Comment: Is it a `vector<std::string>` or `vector<const char*>`?

Comment: i should probably mention that I'm using namespace std. just so we're all clear.

Comment: it's vector<string> (std implied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your input loop with this:

```
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(txtfile, str)){
        vfile.push_back(str);
    }
```

Using `ios::eof()` as a loop condition almost always creates a buggy program, as it did here. In this case, using `eof()` has two problems. First, `eof()` is only set *after* the read fails, not before, but you are checking it before the read. Second, `eof()` doesn't check the range of other errors. When an input line has more than 200 characters, `istream::getline` sets `failbit`, but not `eofbit`.

---

**EDIT**: With the added requirement of limiting the input lines to 200 characters, this should work:

```
// untested
std::string str;
while(std::getline(txtfile, str)) {
    if(str.size() > 200)
        str.erase(200, std::string::npos);
    vfile.push_back(str);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the behaviour he's getting

Comment: Sure it does. He has constructed an infinite loop. After the first `istream::getline` failure, `failbit` is set, but `eofbit` is clear. He has thus created an infinite loop, pushing empty strings into his vector with each iteration. Eventually he runs out of memory. Regardless, he didn't ask for an explanation, he asked for "a way to get around this".

Comment: Always write an explanation, even if it's just for future readers (and other people on SO so they don't think you're wrong `:)`) @crazy_pants you can change your code to `char str[200]; while (txtfile.getline(str, 200)){
            vfile.push_back(str);
        }` and it will be fixed

Comment: @SethCarnegie - 1) thanks for the advice. 2) your solution stops reading at the first long line. I *think* OP wanted to continue reading lines until the end of file.

Comment: i need to truncate after 200 characters. source.getline(destination, streamsize, delimiter(optional, \n is default)) if I were to use it in the way you describe there is no limit on line length by virtue of a string type.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - your solution above stops input at a line over 200 characters. I need it to read the first 200 and truncate the rest.

Comment: @Rob I don't think it stops reading at the first line, `txtfile.getline` is the condition of a `while` loop so it should read until `txtfile` evaluates to false

Comment: @crazy_pants what do you mean "stops input at a line over 200 characters"?

Comment: @SethCarnegie - its stops at the first **long** line. `txtfile` will evaulate to false as soon as it has truncated an input line.

Comment: @Rob so if it runs into a line that is 300 characters, it will read 200 and `getline` will evaluate to false? Why? Sorry, I'm not understanding what's going on here (but apparently both you and crazy pants do so I'm wrong somehow)

Comment: From C++03, 27.6.1.3, *Unformatted Input Functions*: "Characters are extracted and stored until ... n - 1 characters are stored (in which case the function calls setstate(failbit))."

Comment: @Rob ah thank you, I didn't know it errored if it reached the end of the buffer. That seems like stupid behaviour to me :)

Comment: That worked. Thanks Rob. I didn't know (remember) about npos. It's been years since I've written c++ code. Thanks again!